# How to call my method in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, char

I have this declaration in my header:

```
- (char*) randomCharGenerator;
```

And the method itself:

```
- (char*) randomCharGenerator {
    char *letter;
    return letter;
}
```

From what I read on the tutorial on CocoaDevCentral (http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/), I'm trying to call it like this:

```
char *tempLetter;
tempLetter = [char randomCharGenerator];
```

But I get the error: "Expected expression." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tempLetter = [**self** randomCharGenerator];

Comment: If that's the actual implementation of `randomCharGenerator`, then there is a disaster to happen (using undefined pointer to non-allocated storage). Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have

```
tempLetter = [char randomCharGenerator];
```

you need to replace `char` with an instance of the class for which you defined the `randomCharGenerater` method.

This is because in this declaration:

```
- (char*) randomCharGenerator;
```

The `-` at the beginning denotes that `randomCharGenerator` is an instance method of whatever class it's in, so it needs to be sent to an instance of your class. If you had replaced the `-` with a `+`, you would want to send the `randomCharGenerator` message to the **class**, as opposed to an instance of your class.

Note that `char` is a C data type, not an Objective-C class or object, so you can't send it messages. So no expression of the form `[char foo]` is syntactically correct.

Comment: ^ Um... I don't know what the name of the class would be. Would that be the part after @implementation at the top of the .m file?

Comment: If you declared it in the same class you're calling it from, use self.

Comment: CodaFi is right, but otherwise yes, your .m should have `@implementation ClassName` and your .h should have `@interface ClassName`